# Value of $f'(6)$ in given polynomial

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, polynomials

> A polynomial function $f(x)$ of degree $5$  with leading coefficients one $,$ increase in the interval
>
> $(-\infty,1)$ and $(3,\infty)$ and decrease in the interval $(1,3).$ Given that $f'(2)=0\;, f(0)=4$
>
> Then value of $f'(6) =$

**Attempt:** Given function increase in the interval $(-\infty,1)$ and $(3,\infty)$ and decrease

in the interval $(1,3).$ So we have $f'(1)=0$ and $f'(3)=0$

So $f'(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-\alpha)$

Could some help me how i calculate $\alpha,$ thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $f$ decreases on the entire interval $(1,3)$, the root of $f'$ at $2$ must have *even* multiplicity. It cannot be 4-fold or more (since that would make the degree of $f'$ as a polynomial too high), so it must be a **double root**, and your $\alpha=2$.

Note also that the leading coefficient of $f'$ is $5$, which you had forgotten in your development.

Comment: Thanks Henning , But i did not understand the root of $f'$ at $2$ must have even multiplicity. from above function is decreasing in $(1,3)$ so how can we say $f'(2) = 0$

Comment: @DurgeshTiwari: A polynomial will have _different_ signs on the two sides of a root of _odd_ multiplicity, but _same_ sign on the two sided of a root of _even_ multiplicity. Since $f'$ is negative on both sides of $2$, the root has to have even multiplicitly.

Comment: Compare with the behavior of $x^3+1$ around $0$. The function is increasing everywhere, but its derivative $3x^2$ has a double root at $0$.

Comment: Thanks  Henning Makholm got it.

Answer (score 2):

**just a hint**

$$f (x)=x^5+ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+4$$

$$f'(2)=80+32a+12b+4c+d=0$$
$$f'(1)=5+4a+3b+2c+d=0$$
$$f'(3)=405+108a+27b+6c+d=0$$
$$f'(6)=5.6^4+4.6^3.a+3.6^2b+12c+d $$

Comment: This is not actually enough to solve the problem -- you only have 3 linear equations to determine 4 unknowns.